# Rails: Send emails from namecheap email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namecheap

I'm getting the following error when trying to send an email notification:

`Connection refused - connect(2) for "mail.privateemail.com" port 25`

I'm in development mode and this is the setup I have:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true


config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'mail.privateemail.com',
  :port                 => 25,
  :user_name            => 'my_email_address_here',
  :password             => 'password_here',
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Your config seems correct. just double check the address and port. In my case I am using send grid and the config is address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net', port: 587. Also check the ports are open in firewall

Answer (score 0):

Namecheap uses ports 465 for SSL, and 25/587 for TLS/STARTTLS. Additional to this, you must disable SPA in the Namecheap dashboard in order to send emails outside of their dashboard. So I would say all you need to do is disable SPA from the dashboard and you'll be good to go.

As a side note, be sure to store your email address and password in environment variables to keep your credentials out of any version control you may be using.